# BizTalk Flatfile Schema - Nested repeating records

Tags: nested, schema, biztalk, records

I am trying to map a schema like this example, that has repeating records inside repeating records.

Sample File:

```
0000456Toy Industries56Palumbia DriveEnfield   CT06082  98724
302369097   King Toy Store20 Cherry WayDedhamMA02026  TS2349
402369097   036436 Playstation 4 Entert03452449.99  20140826
402369097   036437 Msoft XBOX ONEEntert01234399.99  20140826
402369097   036438 Wooden Horse        07892 59.99  20140827
402369097   036439 Playstation 4 Entert03452449.99  20140827
402369097   036440 My First Brew Kit    99.99  20140828
602369097000100010005I
302369235   Make Believe 342 Brand DriveBridgeMA02324  TS5439
402369235   054324 Playstation 4 Entert53452449.99  20140827
402369235   054325 Steam Box Ultimate  54234699.99  20140827
602369235000100010002I
900033336133310001
```

Sequence:

```
<Processor Record> (one per file | 1)
    <Store Record> (one per store | 1+)
        <Order Record> (one for each order the store had | 1+)
    <Store Batch Control Record> (one per store | 1+)
<File Batch Control Record> (one per file | 1)
```

Each Record (line) will be broken into field elements by positional specifications

I have tried using the wizard a couple of times and manually adjusting the settings as well, but keep running into issues like this one:

```
The current definition being parsed is Root. The stream offset where the error occurred is 0. The line number where the error occurred is 1. The column where the error occurred is 0.
```

I am rather new to BizTalk and was hoping that someone may be able to give me some help on how to accomplish this task. Thanks!

Comment: When running the Wizard, are you noting that each line type has a Tag, 00, 30, 40 it seems.  That's how the Flat File Disassembler know when to switch definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Tag Identifiers to indicate the type of record.

In your case, this would be:

```
00 Processor Record Header
30 Store Record Header
40 Order Record
60 Store Record Summary
90 Processor Record Summary
```

This is how I would do it:

You would have a root node with the following parameters:

```
Structure: delimited
Child Delimiter Type: hexadecimal
Child delimiter: 0x0a 0x0d (newline character of your choice)
Child Order: Infix
```

The node below that would be the "Header" node.

It's properties:

```
Max Occurs: 1
Min Occurs: 1
Structure: positional
Tag Identifier: 00
```

The next node would be the "Store" node.
This is an abstract node, just to be able to capture a store header, a recurring order record and a store summary node.

It's properties:

```
Max Occurs: *
Min Occurs: 0 (depending what's possible on your flat file)
Structure: delimited
Child Delimiter Type: hexadecimal
Child delimiter: 0x0a 0x0d (newline character of your choice)
Child Order: Infix
```

The node below that would be the "StoreHeader" node.

```
Max Occurs: 1
Min Occurs: 0 (depending what's possible on your flat file)
Structure: positional (only you know the exact sequence of fields)
Tag Identifier: 30
```

Next to that, the "Order" node:

```
Max Occurs: *
Min Occurs: 0 (depending what's possible on your flat file)
Structure: positional (only you know the exact sequence of fields)
Tag Identifier: 40
```

Next to that, the "StoreSummary" node:

```
Max Occurs: 1
Min Occurs: 0 (depending what's possible on your flat file)
Structure: positional (only you know the exact sequence of fields)
Tag Identifier: 60
```

At last, at the same level as the "Header" and "Store" nodes, you would have the "Summary" node:

```
Max Occurs: 1
Min Occurs: 1
Structure: positional
Tag Identifier: 90
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I was actually playing with it again and thought about the idea of using some parent node to hold those nodes together and you provided the straight forward approach to do so. Thanks!  Is there a resource that you can recommend to help me better understand the schema and xml part of BizTalk?

Comment: I'm afraid it was just experience on my side. Once you've done this kind of thing, you will always get back to the same type of solution.
Regarding BizTalk, there is a good - basic - certification guide that would help: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-BizTalk-Server-Certification-Edition/dp/1782172106/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409068490&sr=8-1&keywords=70-595 
Good luck!